# Create a web application for a large in php myadmin for a large firm

Tags: php, mysql, apache, tomcat, project

I am planning to create a php myadmin inventory system for a large firm (at least 1000 branches)

There will be a centralized server and database kept in one place. where all the branches can insert and retrieve data from the centralized server. there will be at least 2000 sales bill and 100 purchase bills (at least 1 gb data from a branch)

My doubt is that is it technical feasible for me to use php and mysql (apache) for this project? the data will be vast? do i need to change the front end to jsp and back end to any other database? 
I dont know much about php and mysql database....? any one who went through this scenario already could help me.

Comment: 1000 branches with 2000 sales bills and 100 purchase bills daily isn't vast, only about 7.3 million new sales bills a year; for a properly indexed database it shouldn't be a problem, and well-designed/written PHP is quite capable of handling that workload as well....

Comment: What you do need to consider is resilience (what happens if a web server goes down? do all stores go offline?) and that is a matter of architecture and infrastructure, not necessarily language/database choice

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this question will not stay open for long, it is way too generic, but for what its worth: yes, it is feasible, I did a similar project before.

- You would have to be careful with your **data schema** structure, and
  would need to **tune** mysql server quite a bit, but this is true for
  any database.
- You also might want to employ local servers and **replication** to
  central server.
- Your **reporting** server should be separate, since its workload
  should not affect main data performance.

These are some thoughts that come to mind.